# Working around IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, reflection

I have the following situation:

2 Eclipse projects in the same workspace, Apa and Bepa (pseudonyms for the sake of brevity).

Project Apa references (includes) project Bepa.

I have a class X in Bepa, with public method b().
Invoking X.b() directly works fine in project Bepa.

However, creating a reference to an instance of X in Apa, and then invoking b() on this reference, results in this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method java_cup.runtime.Symbol.<init>(II)V from class de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.util.MySymbolFactory$LineColumnSymbol
at de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.util.MySymbolFactory$LineColumnSymbol.<init>(MySymbolFactory.java:31)
at de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.util.MySymbolFactory.startSymbol(MySymbolFactory.java:95)
at java_cup.runtime.LRParser.parse(LRParser.java:393)
at de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.smtlib2.ParseEnvironment.parseStream(ParseEnvironment.java:152)
at de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.smtlib2.ParseEnvironment.parseScript(ParseEnvironment.java:118)
at de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.smtlib2.SMTLIB2Parser.run(SMTLIB2Parser.java:47)
at de.uni_freiburg.informatik.ultimate.smtinterpol.Main.main(Main.java:121)
at de.uka.ilkd.key.keynterpol.KeYnterpolInterface.main(KeYnterpolInterface.java:36)
```

From what I understand, the culprit is a third-party jar referenced by B. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can only use it from within Bepa, and not Apa. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you invoking the method normally, or using reflection?

Comment: Normally, @millimoose, as far as I can tell. I am doing nothing special at all.

Comment: Hm, this shouldn't really happen when used normally, unless you're compiling against one version of the library, and running using another one where the access modifier of that method was changed. I'd try cleaning and rebuilding the whole workspace to make sure some old class file with a broken timestamp isn't loitering around.

Comment: @millimoose tried that already, doesn't help.

Thinking about it, I am pretty certain it is the SecurityManager messing around, but I have never seen it behave like this. I tried turning project B into a JAR instead and referencing it normally, but same exception again.

Turning off the security manager is not an option due to the nature of the application, unfortunately :-/

Comment: Please include the whole stacktrace.

Comment: I'm not sure why the security manager would ever throw that, that seems like a very low level error that's caused by things being wrong at the bytecode level. Security would throw a `SecurityException`

Comment: There's nothing obvious in the Grappa class itself. It's probably your security manager.

Comment: @Perception Is there anyway I could do a selective turn-off to allow access to the elements mentioned in the stacktrace only?

Comment: According to http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu.princeton.cup/java-cup/10k/java_cup/runtime/Symbol.java#64, the constructor that your code is failing on has default visibility.  From what I can see, your code shouldn't even have compiled.  Is there more than one copy of the `java_cup.*` classes on the classpath?

Comment: @LukeWoodward

Thank you so much, there was indeed more than one one copy on the CP: another third-party JAR also referenced the same library. I managed to resolve the issue by fixing this. Could you please put you comment as an answer so I can accept and give you due credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IllegalAccessError is a subclass of [IncompatibleClassChangeError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError.html).  If an IncompatibleClassChangeError is thrown while your code is executing, this typically indicates that the your code isn't running with the same classes it was compiled against.

In your case, the method that is causing the IllegalAccessError to be thrown is [a constructor of the `java_cup.runtime.Symbol` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu.princeton.cup/java-cup/10k/java_cup/runtime/Symbol.java#64) that has default visibility:

```
    Symbol(int sym_num, int state)
    {
        sym = sym_num;
        parse_state = state;
    }
```

The code that calls this constructor is in a different package and so should not be able to call this constructor directly.  Normally an error such as this is caught by the compiler, as attempting to access a package-private member from another package should cause a compiler error.  In your case however, you don't appear to have any such compiler error.

If you are running your code with the same classpath that you're compiling it with, then I can only guess that the `java_cup.*` classes appear more than once on the classpath, with different visibilities for the constructor above.  The compiler must have found one copy of the `Symbol` class with this constructor being public and the JVM must have found a copy that had this constructor package-private.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much Luke, this was giving me a real headache.